# Check whether application is run in App-V from within C#

Tags: c#, .net, appv

Is there a way to check within my application whether it is run from App-V (or some other app visualization software) or from a local installation?

I looked around but I could not find a clear answer to that...

Comment: Maybe check the execution path?

Comment: Problem is that I don't have a App-V account but one of our customers has and is using it. I would need to put in a check but I can not test it directly...

Comment: I think the applications from app v are stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\AppV\Client\VFS`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check is to verify if one of the following DLLs are loaded by the application, which should always be the case for applications running into a virtual (App-V) environment:

- AppVEntSubsystems32.dll

or

- AppVEntSubsystems64.dll

You can read more about this here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gladiator/2014/09/04/app-v-5-on-application-launch/